# Can I / Should I pool neo4j's JDBC connections in Bolt mode?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

Reading the [neo4j JDBC's documentation](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/), there are two transports supported for connecting to a neo4j server at the moment:

> - through the Bolt protocol (3.0.X) using    jdbc:neo4j:bolt://:/
> - through the HTTP protocol (2.X+) using    jdbc:neo4j:http://:/

Obviously, the HTTP protocol does not need pooling connections (unless it's HTTP/2 which is not the case here). But I'm not familiar with Bolt so I'm wondering if I can pool neo4j's connections in Bolt mode? And if I can, is it like any ordinary JDBC connection and I can use, for example, [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to keep its connections alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j driver handles for you a pool of connection to the database.
Take a look here if you want to see the default config : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/blob/1.1/driver/src/main/java/org/neo4j/driver/internal/net/pooling/PoolSettings.java

For now, you can't configure the bolt java driver via the JDBC one, you can only specify the `EncryptionLevel`. (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/blob/master/neo4j-jdbc-bolt/src/main/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/bolt/BoltDriver.java#L58-L60)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Is that a no then (I mean in conjunction with HikariCP)? Could you also please show how to use the connection pool that is shipped within neo4j's Bolt driver?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how HikariCP works, so I don't know if it's possible to use it in conjunction of the neo4j jdbc driver ...  About the pool from the java driver, there is nothing to do, every time you ask a new session, the driver will take one from the poll or created it. It's plug'n'play